# Print job leaves queue but document isn't printed

Tags: windows-7, windows, printer

I'm dealing with an HP Deskjet F380 All-in-One printer. It's connected via USB to a desktop running Windows 7 Enterprise x64.

If I attempt to print something like a web page or a word document, the print job will show up in the print queue and the printer would stir. By stir, I mean, it would seem to prepare itself to print. However, the print job would then leave queue (I'm thinking the computer sees it as completed) and the printer would never actually print anything.

However I went into Printers and Devices under the Windows start menu, into printer properties, and print a test page, the test page would print out successfully.

I attempted to uninstall and re-install the printer drivers for the printer, but the printer would continue the same behavior afterwards. I also connected the printer to another computer and the printer will print just about anything. I also checked to make sure that the computer the printer needs to be connected to was update to date as far as the OS. The machine is fully up to date.

I played with the way the computer handles printer spooling. Under the printer properties, under the "Advanced" tab, I had the print job print directly to the printer. In all these instances, the same behavior continues. I've restarted the printer spooling service. I've also gone under C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS and deleted files that were sitting in the folder. I have ran SFC /scannnow and the system found no errors in the system's integrity. I had the computer and printer make a cold reboot individually.

The only lead I really have going for me is that since the printer prints on other PCs, I can only assume that there is something wrong with the way the PC is configured.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue just last week, labels being printed just vanished form the print list, and then nothing, printer itself is working, calibrated etc.

And i found out that,
i had 2 configured ports for one Label printer (I re-craetedthe view, with some mspaint magic :P) This issue was on more than 5 desktops, so something to do with a Win7 Enteprise x64 image that we use ... but... onwards

**Solution** : if you see this issue, delete the local port (how?), by changing the printers default port to LPT1-3, click **Apply**, then choose USB00* Local Port ( click once ), and then press **DELETE** should remove the secondary un-needed port.

Press Apply again, just to be safe, Reboot PC, check again, if the problems does not persist, and try printing :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a diffrent print driver such as a PCL 6, PCL 5, or a PostScript print driver to see if you get the same results.  HP should have several diffrent drivers if you go to this link(http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html) and type in the model of the printer.

Comment: The only driver HP seems to have under Vista and Windows 7 for this particular printer is the Dot Matrix drivers.[HP Deskjet F380 All-in-One Printer drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=al-75052-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=1128296&sw_lang=)

Comment: Try the update for Win 7 Install wizard to see if it will find any software or updates for the printer/driver.  http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=1128296#N195

Comment: Unfortunately the HP Printer Install Wizard for Windows 7 did not work either.

Comment: You mentioned that the printer works on other computers.  Are they the same OS?  If so locate the driver on those computers and migrate it over.

Comment: The only driver they have available is the ones that are for Vista and Windows 7 on their website.

I did however try uninstalling the printer drivers and then allowing Windows to re-detect and download the drivers from Windows Update by just plugging in the printer without running the drivers that were on hp's support website.. That did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Printers do sometimes get stuck in funny modes, where nothing seems to fix it. With issues like that I would try a full reset on the printer. On the F380, that's done as follows:

> 1. With the printer plugged directly into a wall outlet, and turned on, unplug the cord from the rear of the printer.
> 2. Then unplug the cord from the wall socket.
> 3. Wait at least 30-60 seconds
> 4. Plug the power cord back into the wall socket first. If the cord has a module in it, make sure that the light on the module is lit up
>      and then plug cord back into the rear of the printer
> 5. The printer should power back on by itself, but if not use the power button on front panel to turn machine back on.

(information from [this link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Ink-Toner-Cartridge-Printhead-Issues/Deskjet-F380-Cartridge-problems/td-p/1924445))

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it does print the test page only, reminds me of a problem I've faced before. However, it should not be this way normally. Go to Device and Printers and right-click the printer driver, choose printer properties, under security tab, make sure your user (and Yes **specifically your user account**, not for example Everyone, or Administrators, if you're a member) has all the permissions checked as Allow (i.e Print, Manage Documents, Manage Printer). If it's not there, add your user account and allow full control.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Right-click the device and select `Printer properties`
2. Select the `Advanced` tab
3. Select the radio button to `Start printing after last page is spooled` (instead of *Start printing immediately*)

Click the `Apply` button, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue that took me weeks to figure out. In my environment we have equitrac for Xerox card swipe and printer auditing. Our issue was where user would print from any pc to an HP or Xerox and the job would appear to leave the print server successfully and then vanish to produce nothing.

We determined the user's account was locked in the Equitrac software so if you run something like that in your environment, check those variables as well.